# Same cookie to 2 domain drupal which is One site

Tags: drupal

I have a Drupal 6.22 webpage. And I have a .de and a .at top level domain. Now the .at domain is an alias of .de. And I want:

- I want to use the .at and the .de domain separately, exactly when anybody open my .at/indexp.php, not drop trough the .de domain.
- I want to monitoring the incoming users.

So I want to hosting 2 site from 1 server, and I want to have a same login cookie, so anybody log in at .at, and navigating to .de, he keep logged in.

I know, the 2 page with same cantainment is killing the SEO, so thats a new more question.

I tried to solve the "Same Cookie" problem width $cookie_domain, but i can't. As I read, it's just working with 2 different server's 2 different sites.

Answer (score 0):

Without some coding to authenticate the user between both sites, you can't do this.

Technically, browser won't send the cookies to other domains. 
If the `$cookie_domain` is `example.com`, then  `www.example.com`, `extras.example.com` will not get the cookies of `example.com`.

If it's `.example.com`, all `example.com` and its sub domains will get the cookies from browser. (note the leading dot before `example.com`)
You can't send `example.com`'s cookies from another domain. That's why you are seeing you get redirected to Youtube and back to google when you login at a google domain.

You can point both domains to the same domain and it will work without a problem. But users will have to login twice in both sites. 
Alternately you can send the user to the other site right after they login.

For an example, when user logs in at `example.com`, when the login is successful, send the user to the other domain immediately and the other site (example.net for instance) can do the same authentication and send user back to the origin site. 
I don't know any module that does this though.